# Angular 2 - dynamic "for" attribute in ngFor

Tags: angular, label, ngfor

When i write dynamic "for" attribute in label, i get error.

example:

```
<div *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index;">
        <input id="ques-{{i}}" type="radio" name="selected" [value]="question">
        <label for="ques-{{i}}">{{question.data}}</label>
</div>
```

the error :

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't bind to
>   'for' since it isn't a known property of 'label'.

the dynamic "id" attribute working fine, please help me to find a solution

Comment: You are missing `of` in `ngFor`, Use this `*ngFor="let question of questions;`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to access label's attribute like this: `[attr.for]="'ques-' + i"`

Comment: Hi thanks it is working!,But why dont i have access to the 'for' attribute? why do i have to use the [attr]?

Comment: Because there are a few attributes like 'for' 'data' 'aria' and probably a few more that don't have "angular" bindings and you can't use string interpolation within them